# Get CurlCode form cURL IO response - Haskell

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, curl, io

I am relatively new to Haskell and I am having some trouble with parsing the response of a cURL request.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import Control.Monad
import Network.Curl
import Data.Aeson

getReq :: URLString -> [CurlOption] -> IO (CurlCode, String)
getReq url opt = curlGetString url opt
```

When I use the getReq function,

```
Prelude> getReq "http://google.com" []
```

I get something like this as a response:

```
(CurlOk, "<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">...)
```

What I am trying to do is just somehow parse out the CurlCode (CurlOk). It is an IO type so I am confused on how I would go about getting the CurlCode from that.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, you can't write `IO (CurlCode, String) -> CurlCode`, but you can write `IO (CurlCode, String) -> IO CurlCode` (which is `fmap fst`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Zeta. Wouldn't this be expecting just IO CurlCode as a result and give me an error? I should be modifying this line: getReq url opt = curlGetString url opt right?

Comment: What's your actual goal? Do you want a `IO CurlCode`? In this case can you can use `fmap fst $ getReq url opt`. Do you want `CurlCode` as a result of `getReq` without `IO`? That's not possible. Either way, you should make clear what you actually want (in the question, not in the comments ;)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas of what you can do. Is any of them close to what you want to do?

```
getCurlCode :: IO (CurlCode, String) -> IO CurlCode
getCurlCode res = do
    (cc, _) <- res
    return cc

printCurlCode :: IO (CurlCode, String) -> IO ()
printCurlCode res = do
    (cc, _) <- res
    print cc

printStatus :: IO (CurlCode, String) -> IO ()
printStatus res = do
    cc <- getCurlCode res
    if cc == CurlOk
        then putStrLn "Everything okay"
        else putStrLn "Maybe not okay"

curlMessage :: CurlCode -> String
curlMessage cc =
    case cc of
        CurlOk -> "Everything okay"
        _      -> "Maybe not okay"

printCurlMessage :: IO (CurlCode, String) -> IO ()
    cc <- getCurlCode res
    let msg = curlMessage cc
    putStrLn msg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getReq` like this:

```
do
  (c, _) <- getReq ...
```

Because `getReq` returns an `IO` monad instead of a normal value, it has to be used in another `IO` monad.

You can learn more about monad and do-notation from [Monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad)